# What are the correct angles in the Top-down perspective?

Tags: 2d, mathematics, camera, perspective

In the following picture it says that in the Top-down perspective the angles are 90°, but if it would be 90° then you shouldn't see the front of the building and the roof at the same time...

So what are the correct angles to get such an perspective?

[image: Top-down perspective]

Comment: You did read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection right?

Comment: Can't understand how to apply these concepts in 2D. the portion of an object that you can see should depend on the distance between you and the object, so if it is far enough you will see both floor and roof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture you posted seems to be seen from a 45° angle. This perspective is sometimes informally called [bird's-flight view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird%27s-eye_view#Bird.27s-flight_view). More formally, it is usually referred to as orthogonal, dimetric projection. Orthogonal means that all the world-axis are all parallel to a screen-axis (world-x is parallel to screen-x, world-y and world-z are parallel to screen-y). Dimetric means that two axis (y and z) are shortened by an equal amount, but the 3rd axis (x) isn't.

Dimetric projection does not use pespective shortening. That means objects far away from the viewer have the same size as those close to it. This makes the implementation of a 2d graphic engine much easier, because it needs no scaling.